Why does an edit to an answer of mine appear to have been edited by "Community"?
This is not a really important question, it's only a matter of curiosity. I made an edit to this answer of mine to add some more details. To my surprise, I got the message "Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed" and then the modified answer appeared as if edited by "Community". Which is the reason of this strange behaviour?

Here's the link to the suggested edit you proposed: https://italian.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/636
My theory on what happened here goes like this: you weren't logged in, so you ended up submitting an anonymous suggested edit. Then you ended up approving it (perhaps from a different browser where you were logged in?). The way anonymous suggested edits work is that, once approved, they appear attributed to the Community user since there's no site user to credit them to.

I suspect that this has something to do with the poor Internet connection I have sometimes at home. I was probably logged out without realizing it due to a Internet connection failure.
